# How to setup templates directory in mojolicious

Tags: perl, mojolicious

In Mojolicious tutorial there is an explanation of putting templates into `__DATA__` section of Perl files.

Suppose, we have templates directory: `/var/www/site/templates/`. How to setup templates directory to use it?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use Mojolicious::Lite -signatures;
# maybe, I need to use custom renderer?
# use Mojolicious::Renderer;

get '/' => sub ($c) {
    # set templates path to /var/www/site/templates/? 
    # use login.html.ep file
    $c->render(template => 'login');
};

app->start;
```

Comment: See https://docs.mojolicious.org/Mojolicious/Renderer#paths

Comment: @clamp I saw it. How to access renderer from inside controller? We have $c - controller object in function, but no renderer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the renderer via the app object: `$c->app->renderer`.
Use the `paths()` method to set your template directories.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use Mojolicious::Lite -signatures;
# maybe, I need to use custom renderer?
# use Mojolicious::Renderer;

get '/' => sub ($c) {
    # set templates path to /var/www/site/templates/? 
    # use login.html.ep file
    my $renderer =  $c->app->renderer;
    $renderer->paths(['/var/www/site/templates/']);
    $c->render(template => 'login');
};

app->start;
```